# CodeIgniter class repeated in url allowed

Tags: php, codeigniter

With a fresh install of CodeIgniter 2 and untouched welcome.php as follows:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

and the following requests:

```
url                                http response expected   actual
/index.php/welcome                               200        200
/index.php/welcome/wtf                           404        404
/index.php/welcome/welcome                       404        200 ?
/index.php/welcome/welcome/welcome               404        200 ?
/index.php/welcome/welcome/welcome/welcome       404        200 ?
/index.php/welcome/welcome/wtf                   404        200 ?
```

Note the last four requests. Why does CodeIgniter exhibit this behaviour? Is it possible to disable?

My naive quick fix is below, but wondering if there is something that can be changed globally to address other controllers.

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {

        $this->load->helper('url');

        if (strpos(uri_string(), 'welcome/welcome') !== false) {
            show_404();
        }

        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

Comment: just curious. in your welcome controller do you have a method called welcome? further why aren't you using ci3 for new dev?

Comment: no, full source of welcome class included. i played around with adding a welcome method, but funnily ci raises an error. asking not for new dev, but i am trying to solve this issue with a legacy app already using ci2. wasn't sure if was ci related or app logic related, seems to be ci.

Comment: i can't replicate this in ci3. do you have any routes defined?

Comment: no other modifications to code were made

Comment: what exactly happens when you go to one of the pages that give 200 when should be 404? blank screen? also your solution isn't really one as someone could just input something else other than `welcome/welcome`.

Comment: index method is rendered with welcome message

Comment: condition checks if uri contains welcome/welcome so covers last 4 requests, if it's anything else, it'd 404 which is what is expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking in CI's code, I think this is caused by the `fetch_method` function of `CI_Router` class. Look :

```
function fetch_method()
{
    if ($this->method == $this->fetch_class())
    {
        return 'index';
    }

    return $this->method;
}
```

So, the default behavior of the router is to set the method to index if method's name is equal to class' name.

You should be able to override this by creating a `MY_Router.php` file in your `core` folder.

```
<?php

class MY_Router extends CI_Router {

    function fetch_method()
    {
        return $this->method;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the 2nd `welcome` must act as an alias for `index` which is why it is working. So it evaluates to `welcome(controller)/welcome(index/method)/param(passed to method)`. But don't quote me on this as I'm not familiar with CI2.

You might be able to do something like this (using your code):

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {

        $this->load->helper('url');

        $seg1 = $this->uri->segment(1);
        $seg2 = $this->uri->segment(2);

        if (strpos(uri_string(), "{$seg1}/{$seg2}") !== false) {
            show_404();
        }

    }

}
```

all controllers would have to extend `MY_Controller` which would be stored in `application/core`